# "Кавычка" или "кавычки"?

Tags: кавычки, терминология, единственное-множественное-число

У меня необычный вопрос. Вроде простой, но неочевидный для меня:

*как называется каждый из этих знаков кавычек (то есть только **открывающий** или **закрывающий**) — **«, »** или **"** — кавычк**а** или кавычк**и**? Если кавычк**и**, тогда в единственном числе этого слова вообще не существует?*

[Вот здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/165-oszp) на Грамоте написано во множественном числе: *Перед закрывающ**ими** кавычк**ами** не ставятся точка, запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие и тире.* Почему?

Comment: Открывающая кавычка-«ёлочка», закрывающая кавычка-«ёлочка», программистская кавычка. А что не так?

Comment: Почему не так? Я просто спрашиваю, существует ли единственное число.

Comment: Существует, но, как по мне, не в виде «знак кавычки/ек», а просто как «кавычка» (эту форму я использовал в своём комментарии выше): *как называется каждая из этих кавычек (то есть только открывающая или закрывающая)...*.

Comment: Просто эта кавычка двойная, поэтому уже может быть только множественное число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово ***кавычка*** (ед. ч.) существует.

Из словаря:

КАВЫЧКИ, **(ед. кавычка, -и; ж.).** Типографские знаки (" ", "" и т.п.) для выделения прямой речи, цитат, заглавий; слов, употребляемых не в собственном, а в ироническом или условном смысле, а также слов и выражений из чуждого автору лексикона. Открыть к. Закрыть к.

Кавычки — парный знак, но он состоит из двух кавычек: **открывающейся кавычки и закрывающейся кавычки.**

Например: https://realadmin.ru/softing/kavychki.html

Зажимаем клавишу «Alt». Не отпуская её, на цифровой клавиатуре (справа) набираем код **открывающейся или закрывающейся кавычки**: Alt + 0171 = «, Alt + 0187 = ».

Comment: Спасибо огромное за все ответы, Sharon! Я только не понял " ", "" и т. п. С пробелом и без пробела — это что за варианты?

Comment: И всё-таки, Sharon, почему Грамота пишет во множественном числе: *Перед закрывающ**ими** кавычк**ами** не ставятся точка, запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие и тире*? Вот ссылка: http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/165-oszp. Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Тёмыч, я думаю, что кавычки - сдвоенный знак (ты по-тихому подсчитай - две склеенные запятушки или палочка, а "елочки" - одиночная "ёлка" - так это ж ваще два изячных уголочка, поставленных на попа и глядящих в одну сторону.). А "кавычка" - это полиграфическое арго.

Comment: Тёмыч, у меня дочь умирала, да сейчас передумала. Она в  паллиативном центре. То есть я как бы не здесь.

Comment: Ой, что-то я совсем ступил! Дал вам ссылку на вопрос про кавычки и не заметил, что мы в нём же и находимся!)))

Comment: Сочувствую вам...