# Как теперь у нас правильно: причем или при чем?

Tags: орфография, предлоги, местоимения

Словарь действительно предлагает **слитное** написание предлога с местоимением? И это уже  не местоимение, **а местоименное наречие?**

1) **В словаре Кузнецова (на Грамоте.ру)**

**ПРИЧЁМ.** I. местоим. нареч. Зачем, с какой стати. **П. здесь эти люди?** П. тут твоя работа? П. всё это? Дети-то п., мы о них не говорим. II. союз. При этом, в добавление к этому; к тому же. Говорили громко, п. старались перекричать друг друга.

2) **Из ответов  Грамоты.ру**

Вопрос № 296541
Как пишется слово "(при)чём" в предложении : (При)чём тут я, если это сделал он?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Пишется раздельно: **При чем тут я?**

Вопрос № 303148. Здравствуйте! Правильно ли написано "**я тут ни при чем**"?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Вы написали верно.

Comment: Не знаю, я привык к раздельному написанию. Может, и неправильно, но так привык. В этом случае зато разделяется такой вопросительный смысл и смысл II по Кузнецову.

Comment: Артем, я тоже привыкла, а также к этому привыкли все остальные пользователи русского языка. Это кажется единственно правильным решением, да только в наше время уже ничему удивляться не приходится. Вот и интересно,  что это со словарем? Они там ошиблись или это вполне продуманное решение наших "новаторов"?

Comment: Кстати, Артем,  вы в своем ответе на вопрос пишете "не при чём". Вот я и решила проверить...

Comment: Понятно тогда!) Кстати, вы про молодца мне не хотите ответить? А то никто не отвечает. :(

Comment: Адрес вопроса тогда дайте. И чуть позже, если можно, а то сейчас времени мало.

Comment: Да, конечно, как сможете. Спасибо заранее. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457423/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%86-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5

Comment: И если вдруг потом ещё сможете по ещё двум хотя бы прокомментировать, буду очень благодарен! 1) https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452540/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8 и 2) https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456902/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b

Comment: А можете ещё тут ответить? Чего без тире предложение не читается в одну фразу? Что это за явление? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457392/Нужна-ли-запятая-или-тире-после-подарила

Comment: Может и могу, но позже.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по издательской практике, в этом значении (вопреки Кузнецову - у него встречаются случаи творческого подхода) пока ещё правильно "**при чём**", напр., из сочинения В. Голявкина (изд. 2019 года): *При чём тут лошади?... При чём тут вагоновожатый?!* https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=Oec2BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT158&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U3fNY3SKTBMN0CxQsS3SOyIIP2n0Q&w=1280
То же с отрицанием. Название книги Дж. Медины (с обложкой, 2019): Возраст **ни при чем**.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что есть у Розенталя:

Союзы *причем* и *притом* пишутся слитно в отличие от сочетаний предлога с местоимением: *при чем* и *при том*.

Указанные союзы имеют присоединительное значение («в добавление к этому»), например: *Эксперимент был проведен удачно, причем впервые; Выступление содержательное и притом интересное по форме*.

Сочетание *при чем* употребляется в вопросительных предложениях, например: ***При чем тут он*** со своими претензиями?

Сочетание *при том* определяет следующее далее существительное, например: *При том издательстве имеется небольшая типография.*

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/37.htm

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но я же  не про Розенталя спрашиваю, а про словарь.Там неверная запись? Если да, то почему и что с этим делать? Словарь - дело серьезное, там скорее отражаются новые правила письма. Поэтому уточните, пожалуйста,  у редакторов словаря.

Comment: Мне уточнить у редакторов словаря?))) Интересно, как? У Грамоты есть с ними связи. Сложно разобраться. Смотрите - и тут тоже (и авторы примеров авторитетные): https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/причём

Comment: Вы же взялись отвечать, вот и уточните.  Для примера. Слово "миллионоголосый" сейчас пишется одной буквой Н. Так оно писалось и всегда (по  правилам). И вдруг в словаре Кузнецова появляется новшество: миллионноголосый. И что вы думаете: все соглашаются, теперь они будут писать НН. И даже могут объяснить почему.

Comment: А сейчас опять одна буква Н. Как вам это? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26831/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Давно бы уже уточнил, если бы была с ними связь. "*Миллионный*" - с двумя. С чего бы писать одну? Да и тут: https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-tolk/304503.html У меня есть предположение, что "причём" и "при чём" имеют разные значения. Добавлять в ответ или сюда, или не нужно?

Comment: Миллионоголосый - одна буква Н.http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x  Добавлять ничего не надо. У Грамоты.ру лучше спросите по "причем". И правила образования сложных слов почитайте.

Comment: Коротко смотрите разницу: *Причём здесь эта книга?!* — с какой стати речь зашла об этой книге. *А при чём здесь эта книга?* — дело как-то связано с книгой, и спрашивается, каким образом.

Comment: Тоже коротко: Слитно пишутся только союзы. Наречия в "причем" в природе не существует. Не надо "стелиться и гнуться" под словарь и  искать несуществующую разницу.

Comment: А чего тогда Ильф и Петров так написали? И другие...

Comment: У них и спросите "чего". До 1956 года было много двойных стандартов. И вообще,  у вас свое мнение есть или всё на других оглядываетесь?

Comment: Я улавливаю разницу между значениями "с какой стати" (тогда и звучит слитно) и "при каких обстоятельствах". В словарях не допускают такого рода ошибки.

Comment: Ага, не допускают. Теперь пишите слитно. И всем объясняйте почему. Мне - не надо.

Comment: Так когда значение "с какой стати говоришь", то вместе. Вот даже и пример такой есть: *Дети-то причём, мы о них не говорим.* А в других случаях отдельно.